# Flutter - SEO оптимизация

Tags: seo, flutter, dart

Есть основной сайт, и есть мобильное приложение написанное на flutter. Есть задача разместить web версию flutter по адресу `m.example.ru`. Встал вопрос сео оптимизации. Есть ли у кого-нибудь реальный опыт внедрения seo во flutter (ssr, пререндер, amp и тд)?

Интересует не код, а опыт внедрения. Результаты. Стоит ли заморачиваться? Или использовать flutter web только в сеонезависимых сайтах?

Comment: `SEO` для `flutter web` пока нет: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46789

Comment: @MiT я читал данную ветку, я понимаю что официально flutter не поддерживает seo. Но можно же использовать amp, или тот же `angel-dart`, упомянутый в данной ветке.

Answer (score 0):

вы можете взять https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer это условно браузер chrome в консоли.

И с помощью него извлечь чистую статику из приложения. Дальше посмотреть на то какие заголовки отправляют поисковые роботы. И перенастроить ваш прокси сервер, на редирект роботов. Что бы если к вам заходит пользователь выдавать ему SPA приложение на Flutter, а если заходит робот выдавать ему сгенерированную статику.

Comment: У гугла куча разных роботов и в случае скрытия данного действия весь сайт может быть пессимизирован, а иногда и вообще удален из поиска, потому что с точки зрения Гугла это мошенничество, потому что роботу ты показываешь одно, а пользователю пытаешься пихнуть второе. Это и 15 лет назад сильным грехом было, а в наше время, когда пользовательские метрики могут стоить больше релевантности контента это может оказаться совсем плохим вариантом.